# How to show the results in real time in result tree controler when running jmx in command line

Tags: jmeter

im running 3 JMX's from main JMX , i run them using JSR223 Sampler 
which executing them VIA beanshell script . they are running one by one.
my question can i get the results of the running JMX in the "View Results Tree"?
in real time while the JMX executing from command line?

Comment: Can you add more info and code? There is no JSR223 controller yet

Comment: sorry i meant JSR223 Sampler there is no code here im asking as concept 
if it can be done

Answer (score 0):

1. Running external JMeter scripts from "main" script using JSR223 Test elements is not the best option, consider using [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) or [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) instead.
2. Beanshell scripting is not the best option, consider using [Groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) instead
3. Running JMeter tests in GUI mode is not the best option, consider executing your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) instead.
4. Using View Results Tree listener in particular (and listeners in general) is not the best option as they don't add any value but consume valuable resources. If you need real-time results consider connecting [JMeter with Grafana](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results).